# Como Obtener valor de appsetting en otra librería de clase?

Tags: c#, .net, rest

Buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy realizando en NET CORE Web API, quisiera obtener el valor de mi conexión del archivo appsettings.json pero en otro libreria de clase.

Este es lo que tengo dentro de appsetting.json

```
"ConnectionString": {
    "conexion1": "Server=server;Database=database;User Id=sa;Password=pass",
    "conexion2": "Server=server;Database=database;User Id=sa;Password=pass"
  },
```

en mi otra libreria de clase quiero obtener la conexión 2 
realice esto

```
var connection= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString:conexion2"];
```

pero al obtener me sale como null yo quisiera obtener el valor de mi conexión 2

Comment: Puedes compartirlo usando dependency injection. https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2016/08/16/diwithconfiguration/

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que podrias redefinir de donde toma la configuracion desde el `Main` de `Program`

Veo ejemplos como esto

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost()
{
    return new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
        {
            IHostingEnvironment env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;

            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
        })
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
        {
            options.ValidateScopes = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
}
```

localiza la parte donde usa `ConfigureAppConfiguration`, sino la tienes es porque usa la definicion por defecto de donde debe localizar el `json`

Si indicas por medio del `AddJsonFile()` un `.json` donde tengas la configuraicon la tomara de alli

[ASP.NET Core 2.0 Configuration Changes](https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-2-configuration-changes)

[ASP.NET Core Configuration](https://codingblast.com/asp-net-core-configuration/)

Comment: consulta y con que comando lo puedo obtener esa conexión ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString:conexion2"]; asi ? porque puse el código que indicaste pero igual sale null

Comment: deberias inyectar la instancia de configuracion, clago como esto `public ConfigInject(IConfiguration config)
{
    string coolestFramework = config["CoolestFramework"];
}`

Answer (score -1):

Buenas la solución que me resulto es agregar una inyección de dependencias  y agregar config en el repositorio de unidad de trabajo UnitOfWork

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego agregue la configuración lo instancia y obtuvo el json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Piero, llevas años en el sitio y aún así sigues poniendo screenshots en lugar de poner el código en texto. Esto no contribuye a una respuesta